# How to retrieve the key value pair present in this JSON

Tags: jquery

I have got the following JSON

```
var response ={
  "orderprintsummmary": [
    {
      "total": "512.70",
      "vendorname": "Inorbit Mall-Food Court01",
      "contact_email": "kiran@gmail.com",
      "crusting_name": "Cruts"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve all the items present in the JSON this way

```
var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(response.orderprintsummmary[0]);
var total = jsonresponse[0].total;
var vendorname = jsonresponse[0].vendorname;
var contact_email = jsonresponse[0].contact_email;
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

But this is working fine if i retrive it individually as shown below

```
 var total = JSON.parse(response.orderprintsummmary[0].total);
```

But i don't want to parse it every time for each value (as i got nearly 50 key value pairs in actual resposnse)

https://jsfiddle.net/x1jhe35n/1/

Comment: Use `var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(response);` and then use that object

Comment: If the response is **string** representation of JSON, then parse it, otherwise  there is no need to parse it again

Comment: The problem is that response is already JSON and not a string containing JSON. So you can't parse it again. At least the way you wrote it.

Comment: index repeated: [https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/x1jhe35n/2](https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/x1jhe35n/2)

Comment: JSON.parse is for string parsing to object

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:loop through the data for each index and get the related attribute.

```
var response ={
              "orderprintsummmary": [
                {
                  "total": "512.70",
                  "vendorname": "Inorbit Mall-Food Court01",
                  "contact_email": "kiran@gmail.com",
                  "crusting_name": "Cruts"
                },
                {
                      "total": "512.70",
                      "vendorname": "Inorbit Mall-Food Court01",
                      "contact_email": "kiran@gmail.com",
                      "crusting_name": "Cruts"
                    }
              ]
            }
    for(x in response['orderprintsummmary']){
        console.log(response['orderprintsummmary'][x].total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only parse if `response` is a string. As it is you do not need to parse because `response` is an object already.

```
//Parse only if `response` is a string
//var jsonresponse = JSON.parse( response ).orderprintsummmary[0];

//If `response` is json then:
var jsonresponse = response.orderprintsummmary[0];

var total = jsonresponse.total;
var vendorname = jsonrespons.vendorname;
var contact_email = jsonresponse.contact_email;
```

```js
var response ={
  "orderprintsummmary": [
    {
      "total": "512.70",
      "vendorname": "Inorbit Mall-Food Court01",
      "contact_email": "kiran@gmail.com",
      "crusting_name": "Cruts"
    }
  ]
}

var jsonresponse = response.orderprintsummmary[0];
             

var total = jsonresponse.total;
var vendorname = jsonresponse.vendorname;
var contact_email = jsonresponse.contact_email;


console.log(vendorname);
```